# Redux-Promise does not prevent rejected promises

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-promise

[Redux-Promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-promise) says: 
 *If it receives a promise, it will dispatch the resolved value of the promise. **It will not dispatch anything if the promise rejects.***

but when I run the code below and do something intentionally to get the promise rejected in action create later I get that rejected promise on reducer too! shouldn't it be NOT sent to the reducer? 
PLEASE do NOT tell me just the workaround but also tell me why it is happening when Redux-Promise says so.

action:

```
  const responce = axios.get(API_URL);  
  console.log(responce);
    return (
        {
            type: FETCH_WEATHER,
            payload: responce,
        }
    );
```

the responce ^ is: 
[image]

reducer:

```
   export default (state = initalState, action) => {

        switch (action.type) {
            case FETCH_WEATHER:
            console.log(action.payload);
                return (
                    [action.payload.data, ...state]
                );
            default: return (state);
        }
    }
```

the action.payload ^ is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating the phrasing:

> If it receives a promise, it will dispatch the resolved value of the promise. It will not dispatch anything if the promise rejects.
>
> If it receives an Flux Standard Action whose payload is a promise, it will either
>
> - dispatch a copy of the action with the resolved value of the promise, and set status to success.
> - dispatch a copy of the action with the rejected value of the promise, and set status to error.

So, there's two different ways to use this middleware:

```
// dispatch a promise directly
dispatch(somePromise);

// dispatch a promise as an action payload
dispatch({type : "SOME_ACTION", payload : somePromise})
```

The "will not dispatch anything if the promise rejects" phrase refers to the first usage - passing a promise directly to `dispatch()`.  You're using it the second way - passing a promise as a payload.

Comment: so in the first case that we dispatch the promise itself, how to handle the reducer part? I mean without a `type` how to get it to the right place?

Comment: In the first case, `redux-promise` see that the "action" is actually a Promise, and runs `promise.then(dispatch)`, thus "dispatching the resolved value of the promise".